# Amazon web services: server-client connection with local machine using python socket ip address setting

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets

I have started using amazon web services for creating server. I need to communicate my local machine with aws server.

What ip-address should I set in the following python scripts.

Server side:

```
import socket
def server_program():
    # get the hostname
    host = "172.17.130.197"
    port = 5588
    server_socket = socket.socket()      
    server_socket.bind((host, port)) 
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:       
         data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
         print("from connected user: " + str(data))
         d=str(data)
         data = d.upper()
         conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

conn.close()  # close the connection

if __name__ == '__main__':
     server_program()
```

Client side:

import socket

```
def Main():
    host = "172.17.130.197"
    port = 5590

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.connect((host,port))

    message = input(" -> ")

    while message != 'q':
        mySocket.send(message.encode())
        data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

        print ('Received from server: ' + data)

        message = input(" -> ")

    mySocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: That strictly depends on your VPC/EC2 instance configuration. Do you use classic EC2 instance? Do you have ElasticIP assigned to the server? Or maybe you use VPC with VPN services?

Comment: Dear Szczad, I am using t2.micro EC2 instance. no ElasticIP and VPC

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your instance has public IP assigned. When you select the server `IPv4 Public IP` and `Public DNS (IPv4)` indicate if your instance is accessible from the outside world. If so - this is the IP and FQDN you can reach your instance. You probably need to open the communication port in relevant security group (AWS autoamtically creates `default` SG).

If you don't have any values there you need to create ElasticIP.

1. Go to `EC2` -> `Network & Security` -> `Elastic IPs`
2. Create new EIP
3. Attach the IP to the instance
4. Add the communication port to the security group (which is `default` if you don't create it manually)
5. The IP provided should appear on details of the instance

Comment: Thanks for helping in setting up the elastic IP. I mentioned the IP address of local private IP in server file and elastic IP on my client file. In addition, I need to setup the route table. Code works! Many thanks Szczad!

Comment: @MaulikMadhavi can you please explain me what you actually did?